# Numpy promotion in integer-float product

Tags: python, numpy

When profiling some code today I was surprised by the following behaviour:

```py
import numpy as np
print(repr(10**19 * np.ones(1, dtype=np.float64)))
print(repr(10**20 * np.ones(1, dtype=np.float64)))
```

which returns:

```
array([1.e+19])
array([1e+20], dtype=object)
```

The latter product is 'promoted' so that `dtype=object`. I find this a bit surprising since `type(10**20 * 1.0)` is `float` in pure Python. Where can I read about this behaviour?

Comment: Not only that but `a = 10**20 * np.ones(1, dtype=np.float64); a += 2` is valid. It shouldn't be if it's of `object` type, surely?

Comment: `10**20 > 2**64`, which means that numpy cannot handle `10**20`, so numpy instead treats it as a python object and lets python do the math. `np.array(10**100)` would make the situation more obvious. Where can we read about this behavior? I do not know.

Answer (score 2):

Numpy first tries to convert python objects into its builtin types.

`10**20` is an integer of more than 64 bits. None of the builtin integer types in numpy have that range. Therefore numpy keeps it as `int` objects with [`dtype='object'`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.scalars.html#numpy.object_).

```py
type(np.array([10**20])[0])
<class 'int'>
ype(np.array([10**19])[0])
<class 'numpy.ulonglong'>
type(np.array([10**18])[0])
<class 'numpy.int64'>
type(np.array([10])[0])
<class 'numpy.int64'>
```

At this point, numpy does not use any of its builtin types or math. When you write `array(..., dtype='object') * array(...)` or something like that, it simply calls the `__mul__` operator of the objects in the first array.

This explains the final result. `10**20` stays a python `int` object. Then numpy invokes `10**20 * np.float64(1)` for every entry in the `ones` array. The result is a python `float` object. That gets stored in a new array of `dtype='object'`.

The type conversion rules are briefly explained in [`numpy.result_type`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.result_type.html#numpy.result_type)

Comment: Makes sense I guess. Do you know if this would be described somewhere in the `numpy` documentation?

Comment: @Svaberg `numpy.result_type` explains some of it. https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.result_type.html#numpy.result_type